# Nokogiri -- preserve doctype and meta tags

Tags: ruby, file-io, nokogiri, doctype, ruby-1.9.2

I'm using nokogiri to open an existing html file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
   <title>Foo</title> 
</head> 
<body>
<!-- stuff -->
</body>
</html>
```

Then I change the contents of the body tag like this:

```
html_file = Nokogiri::HTML("path/to/html/file")
html_file.css('body').first.inner_html = "new body content"
```

Then I write this new document to a file like this:

```
File.open("path/to/new/html/file", 'w') {|f| f.write html_file}
```

And this is my resulting html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd"> 
<html><body>
new body content
</body></html>
```

My question for you guys if it's possible to tell Nokogiri to preserve the original html file's `doctype` and `meta` tags, since it appears like they are being lost/changed when I open the document with Nokogiri and attempt to write it to a file.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What version of Nokogiri are you using?

Comment: Interesting. When I process that HTML in a similar manner, the positions of the `DOCTYPE` and `xml` declarations get flipped, but everything else is kept intact. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/f357da62d5fde62fdd7d).

Comment: strange--that script output looks right to me too (except the UTF-8 gets changed to US-ASCII)--maybe it has to do with the fact that I'm overwriting the old html file

Comment: The encoding is probably getting pulled from an environment setting. I've updated the gist to include the HTML output on my system.

Comment: so weird--the only major difference from your script is that I'm doing my stuff within a resque worker in a rails app--not sure how that could affect the output though

Comment: If you're using 1.9, try putting this comment at the top of your file: `# encoding: UTF-8`

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out:

I just changed the line:

```
html_file = Nokogiri::HTML("path/to/html/file")
```

to

```
html_file = Nokogiri::HTML(File.open("path/to/html/file").read)
```

and now it works like I'm expecting it to. Seems kind of inconsistent, but I'm sure there's a good reason for it.

Thanks for all of the suggestions @ezkl!